# Why using apache kafka in real-time processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-flink

Lately I've been looking into real-time data processing using storm, flink, etc...
All architectures I came through uses kafka as a layer between datasources and the stream processor,  why this layer should exist ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are three main reasons why to use Apache Kafka for real-time processing:

- Distribution
- Performance
- Reliability

In real-time processing, there is a requirement for fast and reliable delivery of data from data-sources to stream processor. If u are not doing it well, it can easily become a bottleneck of your real-time processing system. Here is where Kafka can help.

Before,  traditional messaging ApacheMQ and RabbitMQ was not particularly good for handling huge amount of data in real-time. For that reason Linkedin engineers developed their own messaging system Apache Kafka to be able to cope with this issue.

**Distribution:** Kafka is natively distributed which fits to distribution nature of stream processing. Kafka divides incoming data to partition ordered by offset which are physically distributed over the cluster. Then these partition can feed the stream processor in distributed manner.

**Performance:**
Kafka was designed to be simple, sacrificing advance features for the sake of performance. Kafka outperform traditional messaging systems by big difference which can be seen also in this [paper](http://notes.stephenholiday.com/Kafka.pdf). The main reasons are mentioned below:

- > The Kafka producer does not wait for acknowledgments from the broker
  >   and send data as fast as broker can handle
- > Kafka has a more efficient storage format with less meta-data.
- > The Kafka broker is stateless, it does not need to take care about the state of consumers.
- > Kafka exploits the UNIX sendfile API to efficiently deliver data from
  >   a broker to a consumer by reducing the number of data copies and
  >   system calls.

**Reliability:** Kafka serves as a buffer between data sources and the stream processor to handle a big load of data. Kafka just simple store all the incoming data and consumers are responsible for the decision how much and how fast they want to process data. This ensure reliable load-balancing that the stream processor will be not overwhelmed by too many data.

Kafka retention policy also allows to easy recover from failures during processing (Kafka retain all the data for 7 days by default). Each consumers keep track on offset of last processed message. For this reason if some consumer fails, it is easy to rollback to the point right before failure and start processing again without loosing information or need to reprocess all stream from beginning.

Comment: I just want to highlight the point, that Kafka brokers allow you to decouple producer and consumer systems. (This is part of the "reliability" point above, but I wanted to highlight it as it's not explicitly mentioned.) -- Furthermore, I want to point out, that Kafka is more than a pub/sub or messaging system. It's a Streaming Platform, with message brokers, clients, connectors to other systems, and stream processing capabilities -- thus you might now even need a Stream processing framework if you has Kafka already.